# Select element with a child element by value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

If i have the following XML:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        ...
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>Another one</Name>
        ...
    </Book>
</Books>
```

How can I select the Book element with the child element whose name value **equals** "test" with jQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var book = $xml.find( 'Name' ).filter(function () {
    return $( this ).text() === 'Test';
}).parent();
```

where `$xml` is the jQuery object that represents the XML document. I assume that you load the XML document via Ajax. In that case you can construct such a jQuery object like so:

```
var $xml = $( data );
```

where `data` is the Ajax-response.

Comment: Vidas suppose inside the first book element if i my having two Name elemnt with differnt value then how i can find

Comment: @AtulDhanuka Why would a book have two names?

Answer (score 4):

`$('Books Book Name:contains("Test")')`

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

(This will match "Test" as well as "Math Test", and "This Is Only A Test".)

Comment: Won't this match the `Name` element? The OP wants to match the `Book` element that contains the specified Name.  Or am I confused?

Answer (score 4):

```
$("Books Book Name:Contains('Test')");
```

Comment: Note that contains is case sensetive so you need to update it the jquery with this line: jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

Comment: this will make the search case in-sensitive

Comment: Won't this match the `Name` element? The OP wants to match the `Book` element that contains the specified Name.  Or am I confused?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid selecting `Name` element, use the `.has()` filter function like so:

```
$('Books Book').has('Name:contains("Test")')
```

This will return the *`Book`* items with the name of "Test".